# import database to MySQL using workbench is taking long time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database about 233MB, but when i tried to import to MySQL it was taking a long time, more than 1 hour. I know there should be problem. But i dont have any clue. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you meet so you can get proper help from the community.

Comment: Same principles as [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster)